# Wildfly 10.1 CDI / WELD not working for @Any (war inside ear referencing jar in module)

Tags: java, jboss, classloader, cdi, wildfly-10

My local instance `interFaces` (*in my java war web-app*) is not being injected from a "cdi-able (thejarwithbeansxml.jar)" (beans.xml) jar referenced from my `jboss-deployment-structure.xml` (referencing the module).

**Please see below configuration;**

### theapp.ear

*--- META-INF --> jboss-deployment-structure.xml*

*--- bunch of ejb's*

*--- bunch of wars*

*--- webapp.war* (please see module configuration)

### the jboss-deployment-structure.xml body in (theapp.ear->META-INF)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-deployment-structure xmlns="urn:jboss:deployment-structure:1.3">

<!-- Make sub deployments isolated by default, so they cannot see each others classes without a Class-Path entry -->
<ear-subdeployments-isolated>false</ear-subdeployments-isolated>

<deployment>
    <dependencies>
        ...
</deployment>


<sub-deployment name="webapp.war">
    <dependencies>
        <module name="com.mymoduletest1"
                meta-inf="import"
                services="import"
                slot="main"
                annotations="false"
                export="true"
                optional="false">
            <imports>
                <include-set>
                    <path name="META-INF"/>
                    <path name="META-INF/beans.xml"/>
                    <path name="META-INF/*"/>
                </include-set>
            </imports>
        </module>
</sub-deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

### module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.3" name="com.mymoduletest1">

<resources>
    <resource-root path="thejarwithbeansxml.jar"/>
</resources>

<dependencies>
    <module name="someothermodule" export="true">
        <imports>
            <include path="META-INF"/>
        </imports>
    </module>
</dependencies>
</module>
```

### webapp.war (deployed as part of the ear)

Has a Rest web service class where the injection occurs as follows;

`//expecting to have subclasses of`IActionBase`injected from module com.mymoduletest1.
@Inject
@Any
private Instance<IActionBase> interFaces;`

After reading the Wildfly documentation again and again, I seemed to be following all the rules and that this type of functionality is supported by Wildfly. Example;
[image: Snippet from JBoss]

When I create a sub-class of IActionBase that resides inside the webapp.war, there is no issues. 
Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

### Additional Test Code

The code below (*within the webapp.war*);

```
java.io.InputStream schemaIS = Class.forName("com.fluidattica.test.TestCrazy").getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("META-INF/beans.xml");

            int readVal = -1;
            while((readVal = schemaIS.read()) > -1)
            {
                System.out.print((char)readVal);
            }
```

**Yielded the following result (which indicates the beans.xml is visible and loaded);**

```
19:21:47,335 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1) <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
19:21:47,337 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1) <!-- This file can be an empty text file (0 bytes) -->
19:21:47,339 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1) <!-- We're declaring the schema to save you time if you do have to configure
19:21:47,340 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)    this in the future -->
19:21:47,342 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1) <beans xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
19:21:47,342 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)        xsi:schemaLocation="
19:21:47,344 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)         http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
19:21:47,345 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)         http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_0.xsd">
19:21:47,345 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1) 
19:21:47,345 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1) </beans>
```

Comment: I did a test with Tomcat-8 using weld-servlet 2.4.4.Final, and it worked.